# Is there an unix key store that is similar to "Windows-MY" in java?

Tags: java, security, encryption, keystore

I have a project that requires me to store a user id and password ... obviously I don't want to store the password in clear text.

On windows machines I can use the "Windows-MY" keystore ... but this application will probably be run on non-windows machines as well (Redhat Linux, Solaris, etc).

Is there a java keystore on non-windows OS's that is similar to Windows-MY in that it is tied to a authenticated user?

Answer (score 1):

If there is, I've never heard of it (so that would make it unlikely that it exists). You could try and use the browser keystore though, or create your own one (given enough access rights), but those last options are not tied directly to the user account, cryptographically speaking:

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/keystore.html

For Windows, as you probably already found out, you can use the SunMSCAPI provider (since 1.6).

http://www.berthou.com/us/2007/12/05/ms-capi-and-java-jce-sunmscapi/

You could of course also store it using a salt, hash and iteration count instead (if access to the full text of the password is not required).